# In MySQL how do you use BETWEEN with 'AS' columns

Tags: mysql, database, between

**Part1. How do I search for values on two different 'AS' columns**

**Part2. How do I list top 5 nearest values to 98?**

Example of Query:

```
select 
  TITLE.name, 
  (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
  (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper 
FROM TITLE 
WHERE 98 BETWEEN Lower AND Upper;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part 1), you need to use a nested select, as you cannot use renamed projections (`SELECT` part) as predicates (`WHERE` part) in the same subselect.

For part 2), use `ORDER BY .. LIMIT` to get the top 5. Order by the smallest absolute difference to `98`

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT
    TITLE.name, 
    (TITLE.value-TITLE.msp) AS Lower, 
    (TITLE.value+TITLE.msp) AS Upper,
    (TITLE.value) AS Value
  FROM TITLE 
) t
WHERE 98 BETWEEN t.Lower AND t.Upper
ORDER BY ABS(98 - t.Value) ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias.  This is the error I get with this exact example

Comment: @Jammin: Oops, I forgot about that particular MySQL restriction. See the update

Comment: Thanks for the response.But what is t.* referring to?

Comment: @Jammin: `t.*` refers to all fields in the nested select / derived table. I.e. `name`, `Lower`, `Upper`, `Value`. Replace `t.*` by `*` or by `t.name, t.Lower, t.Upper` if you prefer that